# Side-menu doesn't show in my Ionic app

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am very new with the ionic framework. I am trying to make a side-menu myself. I started the project with this command.

`ionic start testproject blank`

In my new project I added the code for the side-menu from the documentation like this.

**App.html**

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
    <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
            <ion-title>Category</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <button ion-item>
                Home
            </button>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content></ion-nav>
```

And this is my code in typescript.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = HomePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, menu: MenuController) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
      menu.enable(true);
    });
  }
}
```

I get no error in the developer console only one warning and a message like this.

> Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
>
> Native: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
>
> Native: tried calling SplashScreen.hide, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator

Can someone point me in the right direction what I am doing wrong to show my side-menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you move #content in your HTML. I think the variable content doesn't get created.

```
<ion-nav id="menu" #content [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

Also change the line menu.enable(true). It doesn't make sense without an id.

```
constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, private menu: MenuController) {
    this.menu.enable(true, 'menu');
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
```

#### Edit

Persistent menus display the MenuToggle button in the Navbar on all pages in the navigation stack. To make a menu persistent set persistent to true on the  element.

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" persistent=true>
```

If you want to add a button in a single page, just add the key word **menuToggle** to a button like this

```
<button ion-button menuToggle>Toggle Menu</button>
```

Comment: Hi @Melchia thank you for your time. I just moved the variable but the side-menu still doesn't show.

Comment: In that case I think we need to force the display. Check the edit

Comment: I added your solution and still no side-menu and the icon doesn't appear :(

Comment: Try pulling the menu without the icon! with touch gesture! The icon is another thing!

Comment: Oh I am really sorry! The side-menu works now. Thank you so much!! I will do a research myself about the icon ;)

Comment: Thank you for your time sir!